# VB.NET Compare each item in collection to every other item in collection - Threading

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

this is my first time posting so please accept my apologies if im not doing this right and please feel free to correct me for any formatting or posting guidelines. I am doing this in VB.Net with .NET Framework 4.5.2.

I have a large collection called gBoard in a class.

```
Private gBoard As Collection
```

It contains roughly 2000 instances of a class.

What i am trying to achieve is for each item in the class, i want to look at each other item in the class and then update the first item based on variables in the second.

Currently i have the following code:

In the main class:

```
Private gBoard As New Collection ' This is populated elsewhere in the code 

Private Sub CheckSurroundings()
    For i As Integer = 1 To (xBoxes)
        For j As Integer = 1 To (yBoxes)
            For x = 1 As Integer To (xBoxes)
                For y = 1 As Integer To (yBoxes)
                    Tile(New Point(i, j)).CheckDistance(Tile(New Point(x, y)))
                Next y
            Next x
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub

Private Function Tile(ByVal aPoint As Point) As clsTile
    Return gBoard.Item("r" & aPoint.Y & "c" & aPoint.X)
End Function
```

In clsTile i have the following (as well as other items):

```
Private Function SurroundingTerrain(ByVal aTer As String) As clsTerrain
    Return mySurroundings.Item(aTer) ' a small collection (6 items of clsTerrain type) 
End Function

Public Sub CheckDistance(ByRef aTile As clsTile)
    SurroundingTerrain(aTile.Terrain).CheckDistance(CalcDistance(Location, aTile.Location))
End Sub

Private Function CalcDistance(ByVal myPoint As Point, ByVal aPoint As Point) As Double
    Dim myReturn As Double = 0
    Dim xDiff As Integer = 0
    Dim yDiff As Integer = 0
    Dim tDiff As Integer = 0
    xDiff = Math.Abs(myPoint.X - aPoint.X)
    yDiff = Math.Abs(myPoint.Y - aPoint.Y)
    tDiff = xDiff + yDiff
    myReturn = (MinInt(xDiff, yDiff) * 1.4) + (tDiff - MinInt(xDiff, yDiff))
    Return myReturn
End Function

Private Function MinInt(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer) As Integer
    Dim myReturn As Integer = a
    If b < myReturn Then
        myReturn = b
    End If
    Return myReturn
End Function
```

in clsTerrain i have the following sub that is called:

```
Public Sub CheckDistance(ByVal aDist As Double)
    If aDist < Distance Then
        Distance = aDist
    End If
End Sub
```

This runs and works file but as you can guess it runs so slow... I have been trying to work out how to make this run faster and i looked into threading/tasks but it doesnt seem to work. There are no errors but the objects don't appear to update correctly (or at all). The code i tried was:

In the main class:

```
Private Sub CheckSurroundings()
    Dim tasks As New List(Of Task)
    Dim pTile As clsTile
    For Each pTile In gBoard
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(Sub() TileToCheck(pTile)))
    Next
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray())
End Sub

Private Sub TileToCheck(ByRef aTile As clsTile)
    For x As Integer = 1 To (xBoxes)
        For y As Integer = 1 To (yBoxes)
            aTile.CheckDistance(Tile(New Point(x, y)))
        Next y
    Next x
End Sub
```

Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas for how to get this to work?

Sorry for any headaches or facepalms caused...

Comment: It doesnt appear that the task based loop does anything but call CheckDistance which calls SurroundingTerrain, nothing that changes anything. It is not clear it would get the same/right results if it did work if you are comparing everything to everything. I also suspect that only compiles with Option Strict Off.

Comment: Thanks Plutonix, the attempt at using task continues to call the existing methods listed and it is the Distance property that is updated. The reason I am trying to use tasks is to have many items checking every other item at the same time rather than one after the other in a slow and linear manner.